# Pass dynamic JS variable aquired from links to Bootstrap modal in order to aquire data from Database

Tags: php, ajax, database, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have this code for my link in my `index.php`:

```
<a href="#my_modal" class="bookget" data-toggle="modal" data-id='<?php echo $rows['ISBN'] ?>'>
    <img src="<?php echo $rows['Cover'] ?>" class="img-thumbnail product-img" alt="">
</a>
```

And I have my modal in a separated file called `popup.php` and I included that `popup.php` with php include command in `index.php` file.

Following is the mysql query in `popup.php`:

```
$isbn = $_GET['var1'];
$bookfromisbn = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT DISTINCT bk.title As Title, YEAR(bk.date_released) AS Year, bk.price AS Price, cat.name AS Category, pub.name AS Publisher, aut.name AS Author,co.name AS Cover, cp.count AS Copies,bk.isbn AS ISBN
    FROM books bk
            JOIN (SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM copies GROUP BY book_id) cp
              ON bk.id = cp.book_id
    JOIN category cat
      ON cat.id = bk.category_id
    JOIN publishers pub
              ON pub.id = bk.publisher_id
    JOIN books_covers bk_co
      ON bk_co.book_id = bk.id
    JOIN covers co
      ON co.id = bk_co.cover_id
    JOIN books_authors bk_aut
      ON bk_aut.book_id = bk.id
    JOIN authors aut
      ON aut.id = bk_aut.author_id
    JOIN books_languages bk_lan
      ON bk_lan.book_id = bk.id
    JOIN languages lan
      ON lan.id = bk_lan.lang_id
    JOIN books_locations bk_loc
      ON bk_loc.book_id = bk.id
    JOIN locations loc
      ON loc.id = bk_loc.location_id
    WHERE ISBN='$isbn' ORDER BY bk.title ASC
      ");

$sqlbookrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bookfromisbn);
```

And the modal is like following.

```
<div class="modal popupbook" id="my_modal">
```

And with the following js code in `index.php` I'm successfully getting the dynamic variables according to links in console log.

```
$(document).on("click", ".bookget", function () {
 var bookisbn = $(this).data('id');
 console.log(bookisbn); });
```

But I cannot pass this variable to a php variable and use it to acquire corresponding book data from database by using following code in `popup.php`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {var1: bookisbn},
    });
```

Help me to solve this please. I spent weeks and didn't develop beyond this because of this problem.

Comment: your whole concept of ajax is wrong here. Google some basic tutorials for adding dynamic data to your website using ajax. :) always do a little R&D before you try to implement

Comment: I do a research and I have still the same problem. In my netwotk section of the debug area of chrome, It appears all the things as same as I planned. I'm successfully call get method bookisbn?<isbn of book> and It successfully fetch data from database to the console. But it never appeared in my modal, in my main page

$(document).on("click", ".bookget", function (){
    $.get('index.php',{'bookisbn': $(this).data('id')}, function(){
  });
});
this is my code but still I have the problem please help me to see what happened!

Comment: share all your files on paste bin or any preferred environment